# Projection non-expansive in $\ell_1$ norm

Tags: operator-theory, convex-analysis, projection

It is well-known that for a convex closed set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^D$, the projection operator $\Pi:\mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow K$ given by
$$
\Pi(x)=\arg \min_{y\in K} \| x-y\|_2
$$
is non-expansive in the norm $\ell_2$, that is,
$$
\| \Pi(x) - \Pi(x')\|_2 \leq \| x - x'\|_2, \forall x,x'\in \mathbb{R}^D.
$$
See for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426343/prove-that-projection-operator-is-non-expansive) question asked before.

My question is, does the modified projection
$$
\bar{\Pi}(x)=\arg \min_{y\in K} \| x-y\|_1
$$
satisfy non-expansiveness in the $\ell_1$ norm?
In particular, does it hold that
$$
\| \bar{\Pi}(x) - \bar{\Pi}(x')\|_1 \leq \| x - x'\|_1, \forall x,x'\in \mathbb{R}^D,
$$
and if not, is there a "natural" projection operator satisfying $\bar{\Pi} \circ \bar{\Pi} = \bar{\Pi}$ that is non-expansive in the $\ell_1$ norm (or more generally, in any $\ell_p$ norm)?

A related discussion seems to be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615040/does-the-non-expansion-property-of-the-projection-operator-hold-for-all-definiti/1615473#1615473), but non-expansiveness as above does not seem to follow from the $\nabla \| \cdot \|_1$-resolvent of the normal cone operator $N_K$.

Answer (score 1):

The projection in the $l^1$-norm is in general not uniquely determined. That is the problem
$$
\min_{y\in K} \|x-y\|_1
$$
may have multiple solutions. Then in your inequality we could choose $x=x'$ but $\Pi(x)\ne \Pi(x)$.

For example, the solution of the above problem for $K=\{y: \|y\|_1\le 1\}$ and $x=(1,1)$ are all the points on the line between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.